# Why is `urql-cachegraph` `cache.resolve()` expected input / output?

Tags: graphql, resolver, urql

I am following Ben Awad's "Fullstack React GraphQL TypeScript Tutorial" on youtube. It is a few years old, so I am scrambling to modify the code to work with updated packages, specifically here urql-graphcache.

If you are also following along, I'm near the 7:48 time mark.

I read through the documentation about the [cache.resolve()](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/graphcache/#resolve) method.

These are the examples from the docs

```js
// This may resolve a link:
cache.resolve({ __typename: 'Query' }, 'todo', { id: 1 }); // 'Todo:1'

// This may also resolve records / scalar values:
cache.resolve({ __typename: 'Todo', id: 1 }, 'id'); // 1

// You can also chain multiple calls to `cache.resolve`!
cache.resolve(cache.resolve({ __typename: 'Query' }, 'todo', { id: 1 }), 'id'); // 1
```

These examples do not explain the behavior I get in my app that happens to work for the tutorial.

```js
//first resolve call
const res = cache.resolve("Query", "posts({"limit":10})") //Query.posts({"limit":10})

//second resolve call
const res2 = cache.resovle(res as Entity, 'posts') // [Post:1, Post:2, Post:3]
```

It seems like cache.resolve() is actually a wrapper for 2 fundamentally different functions. But why would it be like this?

What is the first cach.resolve() resolving? How is the result of the res act as an Entity?

Is there a way to structure the call so that I only need to call it once?

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same course, and found the solution based on the [urql pagination example on github](https://github.com/urql-graphql/urql/blob/main/exchanges/graphcache/src/extras/simplePagination.ts). You can literally just swap `resolveFieldByKey` to `resolve` in the [source code](https://github.com/benawad/lireddit/blob/master/web/src/utils/createUrqlClient.ts), an it works the same way.

So just use:

```
const isItInTheCache = cache.resolve(
  cache.resolve(entityKey, fieldKey) as string,
  "posts"
);

...

const key = cache.resolve(entityKey, fi.fieldKey) as string;
const data = cache.resolve(key, "posts") as string[];
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of the latest package, we need to use cache.resolve() to find the key and associated data.

return type it needs to be with `__typename` with the actual result value. As we are resolving entities.

https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/graphcache/local-resolvers/#resolving-entities

```
const cursorPagination = (): Resolver<any, any, any> => {

  return (_parent, fieldArgs, cache, info) => {
    const { parentKey: entityKey, fieldName } = info;
    console.log(entityKey, fieldName);
    const allFields = cache.inspectFields(entityKey);
    console.log('allfields  ', allFields)
    const fieldInfos = allFields.filter(info => info.fieldName === fieldName);
    const size = fieldInfos.length;
    if (size === 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    // Check if data is in cache and return it.
    
    const fieldKey = `${fieldName}(${stringifyVariables(fieldArgs)})`;
    const isItInTheCache = cache.resolve(
      cache.resolve(entityKey, fieldKey) as string,
      "posts"
    );
    console.log(fieldKey);
    info.partial = !isItInTheCache;
    const results: string[] = [];
    fieldInfos.forEach(fi => {
      const key = cache.resolve(entityKey, fi.fieldKey) as string;
      const data = cache.resolve(key,  "posts") as string[];
      results.push(...data);
    });
    console.log("results",results);
    return {
      __typename: "PaginatedPosts",
      posts: results,
    };
  };
};
```

Hope this help!